# Navigationbar - Text in the mid (vertical)

Tags: html, css

I have to code a Website for my term paper and I really have no clue how to get my Links in the navigationbar in the middle of my box.

I already looked it up on the Internet but I didnt managed to fix it. It would be cool if someone could at least give me a hint :)

```css
nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: black;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6L589f7/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/y6L589f7/1/)

It would be really nice because I need it but I really dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying a height for the nav bar, you could remove the height and add padding to the links to give the bar it's height:

```
nav { 
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0%; left:0%;
}


nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:15px 30px 15px 0;
    color:black;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6L589f7/3/)

Comment: Ye already played with the padding but always kept the height ... thats the way. Thank you very much :).